# Destructor and python

Tags: c++, python, boost, virtual-destructor

I have some `Base` class in c++. I export it into python using boost::python. But what about virtual destructor? Any base class should have virtual destructor to avoid wrong memory freeing, right? I forget about that and wrote `Base` without destructor. Everything works, but with a lot of memory leaks.

Now I've added:

```
class Base
{
   public:
      virtual ~Base();
      // Other members...
};
```

And after importing of my module in python I get an error:

> ImportError: Base.so: undefined
>   symbol: _ZTI6Base

What I'm doing wrong? And, as I understand, the error causes due to missing destructor exporter for py-module.

Comment: @Ockonal: `Every Base Class should have virtual destructor` is not true unless your base class is `polymorphic`

Comment: @Ockonal:  Are you sure you exported the destructor to the import library?  Are you sure you implemented the function?

Comment: @als can't understand you :( What does `polymorphic` mean?

Comment: @als I'm using derived classes through the pointer to the `Base`. That is called `polymorphic`?

Comment: @Ockonal: Polymorphic Base class means your Base class should have atleast one virtual member function.

Comment: @Als: if a base class has no virtual destructor and you delete an object of a subclass through a base class pointer the behavior is undefined (§5.3.5/3). This is true even if there are no virtual functions. On the contrary, you can have virtual functions without a virtual destructor if you can make sure that you never delete a subclass instance through a base pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing symbol error is probably caused by you failing to *define* the destructor (you're *declaring* the destructor, but it's unclear from your question whether you're *defining* it):

```
class Base
{
   public:
      virtual ~Base() {}
      // Other members...
};
```

(note the added curly braces)

As to your question about whether every "base class should have virtual destructor to avoid wrong memory freeing", please take a look at the FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.7

Comment: the `;` after the destructor is spurious.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do

```
class Base
{
   public:
      virtual ~Base() {}
      // Other members...
};
```

to make sure the destructor is defined

Comment: So, destructors are exported automatically?

Comment: Nothing is exported automatically.